# How can I expand stanford coreNLP spanish model/dictionary

Tags: stanford-nlp

I just run a "hello world" using Standford Core NLP to get named entities from text. But some places are not recognized properly such as "Ixhuatlancillo" or "Veracruz", both cities which has to be labeled as LUG (place) are labeled as ORG.
I will like to expand the spanish model or dictionary to add places(cities) from México, and to add person names. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is some good documentation for the RegexNER annotator which will allow you to add entries to a dictionary: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way would be to use the `regexner` annotator.  You can use this to manually build a dictionary.

Here is an example rule format (separated by tab, the first column can be any number of words)

system administrator    TITLE   MISC    2

token sequence          tag     tags-that-can-be-overwritten  priority

That above rule would mark "system administrator" in text as TITLE.

For your case:

Veracruz                LUG     MISC,ORG,PERS      2

This will allow the dictionary to overwrite MISC,ORGS, and PERS.  Without adding extra tags in the third column it won't overwrite previously tagged ner tags.

You might use a command like this to run it:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -props StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties -regexner.mapping /path/to/new_spanish.rules - regexner.ignorecase -regexner.validpospattern "^(NN|JJ|NNP).*" -outputFormat text -file sample-text.txt
```

Note that `regexner.ignorecase` means to make caseless matches, and `-regexner.validpospattern` is saying you should only match sequences with the specified pos tag pattern.

All of this being said, I just ran on the sentence:

```
Ella fue a Veracruz.
```

and it tagged it properly.  Could you let me know what sentence you ran on that caused an incorrect tag for Veracruz?

Comment: Part of the text I'm parsing is:
**Nombre: Mario Ezequiel Villalobos Gallegos.
Dirección: Luis Donaldo Colosio No.56, Col. José Ma. Morelos y Pavón,
Ixhuatlancillo, Veracruz
Correo electrónico: mi_email@outlook.com
CURP: XXXX801015XXCLLR08 RFC: XXXX801015XX8**
"Ixhualancillo" get the correct label, but "Veracruz" is still labeled as ORG.
Parsing only the text "Ixhuatlancillo, Veracruz" I get both places labeled correctly.
Could be a problem with text length?

Comment: Another question, what is the use of number 2 in the example?: **Veracruz LUG MISC,ORG,PERS 2**

Comment: Here is the full description of the rules format: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/TokensRegexNERAnnotator.html

Comment: The last number is a priority in case multiple rules match the same text, it determines which rule wins.

Comment: The common use case is exact string match for dictionary like "Veracruz", but the rules can be more complicated, like "V[A-Zaz]+" for any capitalized word starting with V, so you need the tie-breaking priority to determine which rule to use if you have both rules.

Comment: Note that larger priority score means higher priority.  So 2 > 1.  It's not like an ordered list.